# Does mmap() perform a write if the written value is unchanged?

Tags: linux, io, mmap

If I repeatedly perform multiple writes of the same value to a mmapped memory corresponding to a file in the filesystem, does that result in multiple physical writes (and as result, medium wear)?

---

Background:

I'm migrating a segment of persistent data kept by a device in NVRAM to flash, and so problems of medium wear start to matter - NVRAM has infinite write cycles, flash - not. But batteries in old NVRAM chips, already out of production, began failing and this pushed our hand.

The two key lines when accessing the file on flash are:

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_SYNC);

file = (unsigned char*) mmap(0, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

in particular of note, O_SYNC and MAP_SHARED - the filesystem is corruption-proof and the most recent data should survive unexpected power-off so I'm not delaying the writes (e.g. we're notified that the supply power vanished about 0.3s before the PSU's capacitors run off and the device is powered off without any gentle shutdown. The fact should be noted in logs, which will be created on next boot-up basing on a piece of data stored before the power-off with this system).

Now, the code is littered with writes of assorted tiny pieces of data the firmware wanted to retain through unexpected reboot but without bothering with files on flash. With infinite write cycles and same read as write speed, it was easier and faster to just write whatever value I wanted, than read, and only write if it needed to be changed. Now the handling procedure has been migrated to writing to flash (through mmap) and I wonder if I should safeguard it against unnecessary writes by reading first, then writing only if differs, or is it just a waste of time and resources and the OS calls handle this internally? (can't really give up on O_SYNC; if I have a piece of data to write, I need it written NOW, not sitting in buffers that may vanish in half a second along with power to the entire system.)

Linux, Arm9.